# Module not found, even though the package 'graphviz' is installed

Tags: python, anaconda, graphviz

I am using anaconda and spyder as environment, and running it on a mac computer. I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/.../.../.../.../...", line 25, in <module>
    import graphviz

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphviz'
```

Even though I have installed the package with `conda install graphviz` and then when I check with `conda list` for package 'graphviz', the package is installed, but I still get the same error. Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to deinstall it and reinstall it again with `$ pip install graphviz`. Sometimes there can be bugs where a module is not fully installed.
2. When this does not work try to do the same with a new project.